# Cross dissolve transition required without using segue

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I want to use the Cross Dissolve transition but not by using a segue. I use the code below to present the new view when a button is pressed but the transition is Cover Vertical. Is there any way of changing this?

```
ObViewControllerMonitorMenu *monitorMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"observationSummary"];
monitorMenuViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The code above now works with the additional line to set the transition type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation to see the list of transition style while presenting a view controller modally, especially at the section `Presenting View Controllers`:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller?language=objc

([Swift Answer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller?language=swift))

And then you can set the *modalTransitionStyle* property of the view controller to the desired value, in which what you want is `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`.

Comment: Excellent - thanks. For clarification I have amended my code to show what it looks like now it works.